# How to convert keys in JSON to lower case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming query that reads data from Kafka in JSON format with 1000+ keys in camel case.

```
scala> kafka_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- jsonData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- batch_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- entity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- time: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- message_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
```

How to change the keys to lower case recursively and convert back to data frame so that i can write using write stream?

Comment: What keys are you talking about? Is this `key` array in `header` or all fields in the schema? Can you show an example of data in JSON format in camel case and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def columnsToLowercase(schema: StructType): StructType = {
   def recurRename(schema: StructType): Seq[StructField] =
      schema.fields.map {
         case StructField(name, dtype: StructType, nullable, meta) =>
            StructField(name.toLowerCase, StructType(recurRename(dtype)), nullable, meta)
         case StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta) =>
            StructField(name.toLowerCase, dtype, nullable, meta)
      }

   StructType(recurRename(schema))
}

val newDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataFrame.rdd, columnsToLowercase(dataFrame.schema))
```